# Opening UserControl in designer causes code Change

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2008, .net-2.0, windows-forms-designer

I have a `UserControl` which is a Tab.  It inherits from a base `UserControl`.  My project is under SVN.

Each time I open the `UserControl` in the designer I have slight code change that seems to automatically happen. Such as `System.Point` changes to the `Location` property of controls.  What I am facing is these small changes ultimately cause a pending change in SVN and if I am not extremely cautious in my check-in process I can inadvertently check-in changes that weren't done by me, but visual studio.

Has anyone faced this?  Does anyone have any suggestions as to a resolution?

Comment: Is it the same changes every time?  Are they significant changes?  If it's always the same changes and they are insignificant, would committing them stop them from happening anymore?

Comment: +1 I face that all the time, especially noticeable with 'System.Point'

Comment: @Zannjaminderson its not the same every time unfortunately.  The changes are disruptive to my UI layout though.  Ultimately it causes alignments and sizes that don't work.  I have a combobox for example on one of the tabs, and it has 'Yes', 'No' list content.  What happens in this case is 'Ye' is visible because the control has shrunk width wise.

Comment: Ouch.  Fortunately for myself but unfortunately for you in this case, I've a lot more WPF/Silverlight experience than WinForms.  I just thought I'd throw that out in case it was a quick way to get around your problem.  Did you try @Henk's suggestion?

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved?  I would have guessed it to be an issue with the parent control of the one in question, either with outright sizing, margin or padding.

Comment: Nothing definitive yet.  And I won't be touching that project until fall again.  Will have another look then.

Comment: Same issue here on one particular form.  The width of the user control shrinks every time the form is opened in designer.

Comment: Do you have TableLayoutPanels in your UserControl?